# Matrix Inequality.

Tags: matrices, functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, matrix-analysis

### Let $A,B\in M_n$ s.t. $A^*A+B^*B\leq I_n$. Is it possible to get an unitary or invertable $J\in M_n$ s.t. $B=J\sqrt{I-A^*A}$ ?

**Comments**: I can see existance of such a contraction $J\in M_n$ satisfying $B=J\sqrt{I-A^*A}$ but not the desired J. Moreover I observe that if $A^*A+B^*B= I_n$ then we will get desired J as unitary by polar decomposition of matrices. But can we hope same thing for matrix inequality also?

Any comment regarding the problem is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question correctly, but when $A=1/2$ and $B=0$, there does not exist any invertible $J$ such that $B=J\sqrt{1-(1/2)^2}$.

Comment: Perhaps you can get a contraction $J$

Comment: Yes such a J is not possible. Maximum one can get a contraction J. Thanks both of you for your comments.